# Storage product testing

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, testing

I know this is out of place (being an active member here I am coming for the help from seniors), but I need some information regarding storage testing, testing of RAID arrays, SCSI, SAS, SATA and also test carried out on fabric manager (Cisco MDS series switches).

I am aware that this is an administrative forum and I would really appreciate if you could direct me to the correct forum ar links where i can learn things.

@ moderators - Sorry for posting at the wrong place, I would be deleting this as soon as I get the help.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a bad request. You don't have to apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm a system designer not an admin so I feel I can help - what aspects of testing are you talking about? Functional testing? Performance? Failover?

Every time we build a new SAN we test failover of every component before we go live by literally pulling cables, obviously we also ensure it works in relation to the design too. For performance we generally use IOZone, initially for baselining then later for concurrancy testing. That said we're pretty lucky that we've used our basic SAN components (MDS's, HP XP/EVA, HDS, NetApps and Emulex cards) for many years so are pretty confident with those parts. What's your objective?

Comment: @ chopper ,thanks for the support...
I would like to  know, what sort of tests are carried out on the cisco MDS switches and fabric manager.
i will be thankful if you can elaborate a little in terms of functional and performance testing ,and  failover as well..How these tests are carried out on the cisco switches?

I know the login services and how the communication happens .But ,in order to test for the performance what all is done on device manager/fabric manager .

what tests are done on SCSI drives to cheack for its performance.

Comment: i would like to add one more thing, what are the test scenarios i need to create for the switch.
All i am familiar with right now is managing the fabric( zoning,VSAN,Port Channel ,trunking).

I need to test my MDS series switches ,the 9500 director and 9120 departmental switch.

Comment: What is it you're trying to test for? Just that your specific switches are good or more looking for limitations?

Comment: How do i check if  my switch ports are good and under what scenarios i can fail my switch ports and check the limitaions.

how do i test Fabric manager ( i have no clue what scenarios are possible to check for the performance of my FM service)

Comment: @chopper- please suggest me.

Comment: Functional testing on MDS series witch?